# how to Get csr from google compute engine and install SSL for google compute engine

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine

hi i have installed lamp stack in compute engine and now bought a ssl from comodo how do i generate a csr from compute engine? and how to install SSL for my VM instance

Answer (score 1):

The only items that matters are what is the OS and web server that is running in your VM. I will assume Apache Linux. You will need shell access to your VM. I am assuming SSH access.

The CSR is the certificate signing request. This is a type of document that details what will be in your SSL certificate issued by Comodo, such as your name, location, etc. You can generate the CSR on any computer. I use OpenSSL to generate a CSR. Comodo documentation on how to generate a CSR:

[CSR Generation: Using OpenSSL (Apache w/mod_ssl, NGINX, OS X)](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1/66/)

Next you need to upload the CSR to Comodo. They will generate your certificate:

[Generate and Submit a CSR](https://help.comodo.com/topic-437-1-843-10843-.html)

Comodo will generate your certificate. Depending on the type of certificate that your purchase, this will take one or two days. Don't forget the validation method that they require. In the document link this is DV (Domain Validation) which means you create a special record in your DNS server for your domain.

Next you will install your certificate. This is web server specific. Here is a link for Apache:

[SSL Certificate Installation in Apache](https://ssl.comodo.com/support/ssl-certificate-installation-in-apache.php)